# How to make UIVIew.transform and UIVIew.traitCollection work together?

Tags: ios, uikit

I need to rotate `UIViewController.view` manually by applying `transform`. However, after such a rotation to landscape, in subviews, `traitCollection.verticalSizeClass` is still `.regular` instead of `.compact`, and `traitCollectionDidChange(:)` is never called.

Is it possible to use `transform` while keeping `traitCollection` working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Applying `transform` does not affect `traitCollection`, since the trait collection is bound to the interface orientation of the view controller, and interface orientation is bound to device orientation.

What you can try to do is to enforce the trait collection that you want on the child view controller `viewController` after you apply the transform to it, via the following code:

```
let traitCollection = UITraitCollection(traitsFrom: [
    viewController.traitCollection,
    UITraitCollection(verticalSizeClass: .compact)
])
parentViewController.setOverrideTraitCollection(traitCollection, forChild: viewController)
```

`parentViewController` here is the view controller which has your transforming view controller in its `.children` array.

Typically, this should work: `parentViewController = viewController.navigationController`

If it's not your case, and `viewController` does not have any parent, you'll need to create some placeholder view controller and add `viewController` as its child.